# How can write to a change log when Entity Frameworks SaveChanges() is called?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Frameworks Code First. I have one entity that I need to keep a change history on. This entity has a double property and when it changes I need to record the amount change amount and date that it occurred. This means I need the old value the new value subtract and post ever time that value changes or when `dbContect.SaveChanges()` it called.

This project is really simple and I would like to keep it this way so I would prefer not add a service layer. I am simply making repository request in MVC controllers. (I know this is not pure but it is very agile)

How can I intercept changes to this entity so I can write to a change log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the [ObjectContext.SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event, and then use the [ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectstatemanager.aspx) property to look for the [ObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx)(s) for the entity type that you are interested in.

`ObjectStateEntry` has properties to access the `CurrentValues` and `OriginalValues`, or only the original values for updatable properties using the `GetUpdatableOriginalValues` method.

Note:  I have not tested this, but hopefully it will work for you.